# Telegram Bot SDK add command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, telegram

I am using laravel 5.4 and [Telegram Bot SDK](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk).

I want to add a command to my bot.

I try to add `StartCommand` of [the documentation](https://irazasyed.github.io/telegram-bot-sdk/usage/commands/#introduction) but I get error.

```
Command class "Vendor\App\Commands\StartCommand" not found!
```

but the documentation says:

> You may store your custom commands in any directory as long as your commands can be autoloaded based on your `composer.json` settings

and I store `StartCommand class` in `app\StartCommand.php`.

here is my `composer.json`:

```
...
,
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
...
```

here is telegrom-bot-sdk config at `config\telegram.php:

```
...
    'commands' => [
        Telegram\Bot\Commands\HelpCommand::class,
        Vendor\App\Commands\StartCommand::class,
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to use current namespace of my file.

If I store command file in `app\`, I should use

```
namespace App;
```

in my code instead of

```
namespace Vendor\App\Commands;
```

and in `config\telegram.php`:

```
...
    'commands' => [
        Telegram\Bot\Commands\HelpCommand::class,
        App\StartCommand::class,
    ],
];
```